# Map type definition where value corresponds to key

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

How can I define a map where each key has a certain type assigned ?

This is the type def:

```
type Data = {
  articles: Article[],
  comments: Comment[],
  ...
}
```

And the map def has to accept only keys from that type, but the values have to match the keys:

```
type MyMap = <K extends keyof Data>Map<K, Data[K]>; // <- doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like the following:

```
interface StrictMap<T extends Record<string, any>>
  extends Map<keyof T, T[keyof T]> {
  clear(): void;
  delete(key: keyof T): boolean;
  get<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] | undefined;
  has(key: keyof T): boolean;
  set<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]): this;
  readonly size: number;
}
```

This is a copy of the `Map` type, but I have changed the generics to accept only an object-like value (which will retain the exact key-value mappings).

I have also overridden most of the methods so that the types are stricter. The only one I have left out is `forEach` which uses the existing `Map.forEach` as our new type extends the `Map<K, V>` type.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a generic type, that uses a [distributed conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

```
type MyMap<O, K extends keyof O = keyof O> = K extends any ? Map<K, O[K]> : never;
```

This builds a union of `Map` types for each key (`K`) from `Data` and with the associated value type (`O[K]`):

```
type MyDataMap = MyMap<Data>;
// Map<"articles", Article[]> | Map<"comments", Comment[]>
```

---

To break it down a little, the `MyMap<Data>` is the same as `MyMap<Data, keyof Data>` (due to the default on the second generic type). `keyof Data` can also be written as a union type of `"articles" | "comments"`:

```
MyMap<Data>
// "unfurls" to 
MyMap<Data, "articles" | "comments">
// O--^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----- K
```

The conditional type of `K extends any` is then applied to each member of the `"articles" | "comments"` union. So `MyMap` distributes on each element, effectively giving:

```
MyMap<Data, "articles"> | MyMap<Data, "comments">
```

When ultimately gives:

```
Map<"articles", Article[]> | Map<"comments", Comment[]>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work when using the map. For example `map.get("comments")` throws some type rror